# R - count number of items in a piped list

Tags: r, count, aggregate

I have a column with a piped list of identifiers

```
Identifier
O75496|P62979|P62987|P0CG47|P0CG48|O00487|P25786
P28066|P60900|O14818|P20618|P40306
Q99436|P28062|P28065
P28062|P28065|P62191|P35998|P17980|P43686
```

How do I produce a column of the numbers of identifiers in each row?
Output to read something like this

```
Identifier                                          Count
O75496|P62979|P62987|P0CG47|P0CG48|O00487|P25786    7
P28066|P60900|O14818|P20618|P40306                  5
Q99436|P28062|P28065                                3
P28062|P28065|P62191|P35998|P17980|P43686           6
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `length(strsplit(a, "\\|")[[1]])`

Comment: post the output of `dput(df)`

Comment: Try `stringi::stri_count_fixed(df$Identifier, "|") + 1L`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sapply(strsplit(df$Identifier, '[|]'), length)
```

for unique cases, just add the `unique` function

```
sapply(strsplit(df$Identifier, '[|]'), function(i) length(unique(i)))
```

Comment: Probably `lengths(strsplit(as.character(df$Identifier), '|', fixed = TRUE))` will be more efficient. And you will need to convert to character eitherway probably.

Answer (score 1):

A base R option without splitting would be

```
df1$Count <- nchar(gsub("[^|]", "", df1$Identifier)) + 1L
df1$Count
#[1] 7 5 3 6
```

Or with `gregexpr`

```
sapply(gregexpr("[|]", df1$Identifier), 
      function(x) sum(attr(x, "match.length"))+1)
#[1] 7 5 3 6
```

Comment: Thank you for all replies. I tried several of the different answers and they all worked as I expected. Apologies if I didn't find the duplicate answers from previous such-like questions

Comment: PS If I want to count only the unique entries per piped list, what argument can I add to the above solutions?

Comment: @Beej In that case `sapply(strsplit(df1$Identifier, function(x) length(unique(x)))`

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't appear to work for me

Comment: @Beej I missed the `split`. i.e. `sapply(strsplit(df1$Identifier, "[|]"), function(x) length(unique(x)))`

Comment: Thank you, that worked a treat!